# Mercurial subrepository different folder

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-subrepos

I have different repositories on my server, the main repo of the application (MyApplication A, B, C) and the library repo (I'd like to reuse this repo in many applications).

on server side

```
\\Server\Share\MyApplicationA\ 
\\Server\Share\MyApplicationB\
\\Server\Share\MyApplicationC\
\\Server\Share\MyLibrary\
```

When I clone the repo I put the LibraryRepo inside the application in use (A, B or C).
on my computer

```
C:\MyApplicationA\ 
C:\MyApplicationA\MyLibrary\

C:\MyApplicationB\ 
C:\MyApplicationB\MyLibrary\

C:\MyApplicationC\ 
C:\MyApplicationC\MyLibrary\
```

This is my .hgsub

```
MyLibrary = MyLibrary
```

When I try to push on remote repo (on server) I get this error:

> repository Z:/SERVER/Share/MyApplicationA/MyLibrary non trovato

...because the Library Repo on server is on different folder.

I have to create/link the subrepo on server side before?

To manage the repository I use TortoiseHG (Mercurial).
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that work on fake remote repo (fake becasue the remote repo is on my external HD and simulate my SERVER share) but doesn't work on real repo on my server.

Open DOS command line (with Admin rights), write:

```
mklink /D MyLibrary ".\..\MyLibrary"
```

How to create symlink on remote path ?
Thanks for any suggestions.